# How to sum a value in array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to push and plus value in array. I tried it but it is giving 'NaN'. I think it can be done by defining array type to integer. Can it is possible. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dah7J/).

```
var total=[];
$('.check').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).find('div').each(function(index, element) {
        total[index]+= parseInt($(this).text())
    });
});

$('.update').find('div').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text(total[index])
});
```

Comment: Well you're using `+=` on an empty array, so it's trying to take nothing and add to it, hence `NaN`

Comment: "Plus" is not a verb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to add to nothing.

Here's one solution:

```
total[index] = (total[index] || 0) + parseInt($(this).text())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yfC5Z/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(this).find('div').each(function(index, element) {
    if (total[index] == undefined) total[index] = 0;
    total[index]+= parseInt($(this).text())
});
```